# variable array value depending on increasing row number

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

A short description of my program that I am working on: I input a number `n` which means number of rows. `a b` variables stands for dimensions of rectangle - its second input. Then, most important part. I have a person which is standing on this rectangle and has a starting position `x y` and starting direction `s`. `x y` are in range as you can see in the code. Directions are S,J,V,Z (N,S,E,W). So this input is in 3rd row and it consists of 3 parameters: `x y s`. As you can see in my code, if I input S, my `y` value increases by +1, J decreases `y` value by -1, etc..

At the end of my code is a for loop, which outputs all inputs at once, because I don not want it output right away, after each input.

My problem is, I input:

`2` // number of tasks or rows
`5 8` // a b dimensions
Uloha 1 (Task 1):
`4 5 S` // x y s (S means y+1)
Uloha 2:
`2 3 Z` // x y s (Z means x-1)

Output:

`1 3 Z` // here should be `4 6 S`

`1 3 Z`

I press enter, and I get two rows of output but the values of `x y s` are only final values of the second row, so it doesnt remember each task, logically. The last input value of `x y s` changes every time I input new row. And also, there is a if condition which is not working too, when `x` `y` goes under 0 or above `a` or `b`, it should print `SPADOL`.

What do you think, any suggestions? Btw, Im just a beginner in C++. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n; // pocet uloh
int a; // rozmer obdlznika a
int b; // rozmer obdlznika b
int x;
int y;
string s; // smer
int i;

vector<string> inputs;


int main() {

    cin >> n;

    while(!((n >= 1)&&(n <=15000)))
    {
        cout << "max 15000" << flush;
        cin >> n;
    }


    cin >> a >> b;

    while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) | (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)))
    {
        cout << "max 100" << flush;
        cin >> a >> b;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;

        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cin >> s;

        while(!((x>=0)&&(x<=a))) {
            cout << "Try Again x: " << flush;
            cin >> x;
        }
        while(!((y>=0)&&(y<=b))) {
            cout << "Try Again y: " << flush;
            cin >> y;
        }


        if (s == "S"){
            y = (y+1);
        }else if (s == "J"){
            y = (y-1);
        }else if (s == "V"){
            x = (x+1);
        }else if (s == "Z"){
            x = (x-1);
        }
        if(!((x>=0)&&(x<=a) | (y>=0)&&(y<=b))){
            cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << s << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
        }


        // inputs.push_back(x);
        // inputs.push_back(y);
        // inputs.push_back(z);
        //for(vector<string>::iterator it = inputs.begin(); it != inputs.end(); ++it)
        //{ 
        //cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << *it << endl;
        //}

    }    // koniec for

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << s << endl;

    } 

system("pause");
}
```

EDIT:>

```
    #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string>

        using namespace std;
        int n; // pocet uloh
        int a; // rozmer obdlznika a
        int b; // rozmer obdlznika b
        int *x = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        int *y = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        string *s = (string*)malloc(n*sizeof(string)); // smer
        int i;
        int d;

        static const char alpha[] = {'D', 'L', 'P'};
        char genRandom()
        {
          return alpha[rand() % strlen(alpha)];
        }
        // end of generator


        int main() {

         cin >> n;

         while(!((n >= 1)&&(n <=15000)))
         {
         cout << "max 15000" << flush;
         cin >> n;
    }


    cin >> a >> b;

    while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) & (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)&&(a!=b)))
    {
    cout << "chyba max 100 alebo a!=b" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {    
    cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;

    cin >> x[i];
    cin >> y[i];
    cin >> s[i];

    while(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a))) {
    cout << "Try Again x: " << flush;
    cin >> x[i];}
    while(!((y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))) {
    cout << "Try Again y: " << flush;
    cin >> y[i];}


    if (s[i] == "S"){
    y[i] = (y[i]+1);
    }else if (s[i] == "J"){
    y[i] = (y[i]-1);
    }else if (s[i] == "V"){
    x[i] = (x[i]+1);
    }else if (s[i] == "Z"){
    x[i] = (x[i]-1);
    }
    cin >> d;
    while(!((d>=1)&& (d<=200))) {
    cout << "Try Again d: " << flush;
    cin >> d;}


   for (int counter=0; counter<d; counter++)
    {
   cout << genRandom();
    }
cout << endl;

}    // koniec for

for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
if(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a) & (y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))){
cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
}else{
cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << endl;
}

} 

free(x);free(y);free(s);

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) | (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)))` Did you mean `&&` perhaps?

Comment: do you mean use `&&` instead of `|`?

Comment: @user3286879 at least you should use `||` instead of `|` when you want a locical `OR`. But I don't think that is the main problem here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I used `||` or `&` but it is not working anyway... only `&` seems to work..but lets get back to the main problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put brackets when you use the or condition (a&&b) | (c&&d).

```
if(!(((x>=0)&&(x<=a)) | ((y>=0)&&(y<=b)))){
```

This code is working for me. You can use the c++ vector to store the values and print them at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int n; // pocet uloh
int a; // rozmer obdlznika a
int b; // rozmer obdlznika b
int i;
int d;

static const char alpha[] = {'D', 'L', 'P'};
char genRandom()
{
    return alpha[rand() % strlen(alpha)];
}
// end of generator

int main() {

    cin >> n;
    vector<int> x(n);
    vector<int> y(n);
    vector<string> s(n);

    while(!((n >= 1)&&(n <=15000)))
    {
        cout << "max 15000" << flush;
        cin >> n;
    }


    cin >> a >> b;

    while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) & (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)&&(a!=b)))
    {
        cout << "chyba max 100 alebo a!=b" << endl;
        cin >> a >> b;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "x: ";
        cin >> x[i];
        cout << "y: ";
        cin >> y[i];
        cout << "s: ";
        cin >> s[i];

        while(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a))) {
            cout << "Try Again x: " << flush;
            cin >> x[i];}
            while(!((y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))) {
                cout << "Try Again y: " << flush;
                cin >> y[i];}


                if (s[i] == "S"){
                    y[i] = (y[i]+1);
                }else if (s[i] == "J"){
                    y[i] = (y[i]-1);
                }else if (s[i] == "V"){
                    x[i] = (x[i]+1);
                }else if (s[i] == "Z"){
                    x[i] = (x[i]-1);
                }
                cin >> d;
                while(!((d>=1)&& (d<=200))) {
                    cout << "Try Again d: " << flush;
                    cin >> d;}


                    for (int counter=0; counter<d; counter++)
                    {
                        cout << genRandom();
                    }
                    cout << endl;

    }    // koniec for

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        if(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a) & (y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))){
            cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << endl;
        }

    } 


}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your main problem. Can you explain better what's wrong and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I updated my question, see examples...Im not getting every single input..every time my x and y and s values are from last input....I need output from every one input..not just from last one..Last one is copied into every other row and it shouldnt be..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check if this solve your problem

Comment: Im getting error `invalid conversion from void* to int* `

Comment: I added the casts to my answers. Try now

Comment: I fixed the rest of my code but program stopps working after output. wondering why?

Comment: @ferii You have to deallocate the memory. Put free(x); free(y); free(s); at the end of your program

Comment: I added free at the end but still, I add my updated code with generator I created recently, so check it out please.

Comment: @ferii move the three lines with the malloc inside the main immediately after the cin >> n; Your problem is that when you allocate the space n is not yet defined

Comment: @daniele, still not working, I found out that I dont get only first output, Im not getting the rest..it crashes right after first output is printed out..

Comment: @daniele so everything you did is that you added 3 lines to declare vectors right?

Comment: yes I changed the vectors definitions and fixed the imports. You were importing twice <string> and never <string.h>