# How can I deallocate array memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

My program stops working because of this output. How can I deallocate it?
I tried what I have in my code but that doesnt help.
full code can be found here: [full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657721/variable-array-value-depending-on-increasing-row-number)

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    if (
       !( (x[i] >= 0) && (x[i] <= a) &
          (y[i] >= 0) && (y[i] <= b)
        )
    ) {
        cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
    } else {
       cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << endl;
    } // ALLOCATION IS DONE AT THIS POINT

    delete [] x;  
    delete [] y;  
    delete [] s;
}
```

When I run this code, I start input x and y and right after I type y value, program stops working. When I input only one row, program executes perfect, but problem comes when I want to input more than one row, ..Program crashes right after first output is printed out.
My full code with vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// vector<string> inputs;
int n; // pocet uloh
int a; // rozmer obdlznika a
int b; // rozmer obdlznika b
vector<int> x;
vector<int> y;
vector<string> s;
int i;
int d;

static const char alpha[] = {'D', 'L', 'P'};
char genRandom()
{
    return alpha[rand() % strlen(alpha)];
}
// end of generator


int main() {

    cin >> n;

    while(!((n >= 1)&&(n <=15000)))
    {
           cout << "max 15000" << flush;
           cin >> n;
           }


    cin >> a >> b;

    while(!((a >= 1)&&(a <=100) & (b >= 1)&&(b <= 100)&&(a!=b)))
    {
           cout << "chyba max 100 alebo a!=b" << endl;
           cin >> a >> b;
           }


        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
               {    
                    cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl;

                    cin >> x[i];
                    cin >> y[i];
                    cin >> s[i];

                    while(!((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a))) {
                    cout << "Try Again x: " << flush;
                    cin >> x[i];}
                    while(!((y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b))) {
                    cout << "Try Again y: " << flush;
                    cin >> y[i];}


                    if (s[i] == "S"){
                          y[i] = (y[i]+1);
                          }else if (s[i] == "J"){
                                y[i] = (y[i]-1);
                                }else if (s[i] == "V"){
                                      x[i] = (x[i]+1);
                                      }else if (s[i] == "Z"){
                                            x[i] = (x[i]-1);
                                            }
                    cin >> d;
                    while(!((d>=1)&& (d<=200))) {
                    cout << "Try Again d: " << flush;
                    cin >> d;}


                   for (int counter=0; counter<d; counter++)
                   {
                   cout << genRandom();
                   }
                   cout << endl;

          }    // koniec for

          for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
                                     {
                                         if(!(((x[i]>=0)&&(x[i]<=a)) | ((y[i]>=0)&&(y[i]<=b)))){
                                                  cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
                                                  }else{
                                                  cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << endl;

                                                  }

                                     } 




system("pause");

}
```

Comment: You don't show the full code... Where is the allocation done?

Comment: When providing code to show a problem, include all the code required to produce the error and strip out code that is unrelated to the error. For example, most of the code you provided (the entire `if`/`else` block) does nothing with allocation or deallocation so it's pure noise to the question. As a bonus, if you did that before posting your question, you would probably have seen that you `delete [] array;` inside your loop -- thus allowing you to figure out the mistake before posting.

Comment: The linked code uses `malloc`. You need to use  `free` to release in that case, not `delete`.

Comment: @Mat, I used free before, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the arrays `x`, `y` and `s` to be dynamically allocated via `new[]` and `n > 1`, your loop will deallocate `x`, `y`, `s` the first time around, and then will attempt to read `x[i]` the next iteration.

You should move the `delete[]` outside of the loop, or even better, you should use containers that clear themselves up automagically, like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> y;
std::vector<int> s;

for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    if (
       !( (x[i] >= 0) && (x[i] <= a) &
          (y[i] >= 0) && (y[i] <= b)
        )
    ) {
        cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << "SPADOL" << endl;
    } else {
       cout << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << ' ' << s[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clear up the magic: Vectors are allocated on the stack, it's elements are allocated on the heap. So it will internally keep track of it's allocations and deallocations.

Comment: I tried to use vectors like you showed in your code but thats not working. Something might be missing.

Comment: @ferii, you need to initialize the vectors, of course.

Comment: @Jefffrey I updated with full code using vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t allocate with the keyword "new", you never have to call delete. You only have to deallocate if you allocate on the heap. Use standard lib classes, to let them do the new/delete on the heap internally.

Comment: I would love to but Iam a newbie in C++ ..Its not very clear to me what you just said.

Comment: We've all been noobs :) I just early on put a mental note of "new". Whenever it's used it must be paired with delete. And you can in almost all cases avoid using them, by using types in the std:: namespace. I recommend you to read up on stack vs heap. It's very useful to know.